# What's causing "hanging" JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I find that my script is "hanging" after clicking around afew times

http://jsfiddle.net/Zn7br/4/

or

video http://screenr.com/6g6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox and debug it.  Open your webpage, start firebug, click on the Script tab and put a breakpoint on the line:

`var $tips = $(".slideOut");`

When your breakpoint is hit, you can use F10 to step over the code & hopefully see where it's hanging. I'm a jquery novice and it's helped me loads!